# Cannot run published website that using database

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-2.1

I started to code my new website using ASP.net core
Everything runs properly with development environment: Open VSCode and F5 to run.
But after i publish all of them to IIS, it runs with 404 error

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web
>   address: https://localhost:1111/ HTTP ERROR 404

The error page is displayed when the page connects database to runs backend actions.
Any actions in published web that don't use database such as href to another link, run javascript validation, ... would run with no 404 error

Do I miss anything or make something wrong?

here're the steps that i did to publish my site

- open terminal and run **dotnet publish --configuration Release**
- copy publish folder in bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish to the publish folder in IIS setting
- open IIS and add application pool with .net CLR version is No managed code
- add website with application pool above, bind type is https, hostname is localhost, and tick all 3 checkboxes (Require server name indication, Disable HTTP/2, disable OCSP Stapling), SSL certificate is **IIS Express Development Certificate**

I forgot the page that guided me those steps

Comment: VS code should use IIE express. That's  different from IIS. So have you checked IIS log to get the sub-status code? Connect database shouldn't return 404 unless wrong handler is handling the request. Please check IIS log first, if the status code is 404.4. Then please ensure ASp.net core web hosting bundle has been installed on your server.

Comment: Dear Jokies
here's the log when the error occurs
> ::1, -, 10/31/2019, 21:51:55, W3SVC3, DESKTOP-3DJJPOE, ::1, 1601, 951, 2127, 200, 0, GET, /, -,
> ::1, -, 10/31/2019, 21:52:15, W3SVC3, DESKTOP-3DJJPOE, ::1, 10485, 1326, 222, 404, 0, POST, /, -,
the web submits a login form with username, password and perform a verify action in controller where it interacts to database. then it returns the 404 error above
but when i click a link that redirect to another page or perform an javascript validation then no problem occurs
i installed .NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows (v2.2.4)

Comment: "But after i publish all of them to IIS". How? You need to edit your question to reveal the exact steps you did.

Comment: ok, i edited the question in my post above

Comment: @MingHieu I notice that same URL https://localhost:1111/ works fine with GET METHOD, but fail with POST method. Did your Controller support  POST method for URL "http://localhost:1111/"？ Because it looks doesn't like an application error

Comment: @Jokies Ding: but i'm wondering that why there's difference between 2 environments, one works fine and the other doesn't

Comment: It depend on what the request  POST http://localhost:1111 is doing.  IIS express use your system login account as application user while IIS always use application pool identity in in proc mode. So if app pool identity don't have enough permission to access any file. Your web app would probably return 404 based on application logic. You could use Process monitor to check this issue

Comment: @JokiesDing. does that mean i have any wrong config while building my web app in IIS, or i miss any prerequisite installation. and could you show me where to use Process monitor to check this issue

Comment: @jokiesding: Thanks for your hint about user used by IIS and IIS express. I have found the cause myself. The reason that the web app return a 404 page when I post something to backend to process database is I used windows authentication in my database connection string. So it couldn't access the database when I publish to IIS. When i change connection using sql server authentication, it works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself have found the cause. The reason that the web app return a 404 page when I post something to backend to process database is I used windows authentication in my database connection string. So it couldn't access the database when I publish to IIS. When i change connection using sql server authentication, it works properly